# H5P content for Moodle with Unity 3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, moodle, h5p

I would like to create content with Unity for using with Moodle. Such content should be able to store user's score, and other variables as well. I have read about SCORM, xAPI, Moodle API, LTI, etc... But H5P is what I need to use because of the restrictions with my institution.

I know I can interact with the browser from Unity, using WebGL. But I can't find information about H5P javascript API for Moodle... Anyone can help me please?

Comment: There's no special H5P JavaScript API for moodle - it runs across platforms. Have you already had a look at the H5P developer documentation at [https://h5p.org/developers](https://h5p.org/developers)?

Comment: Yes @OliverTacke. I checked the official documentation. I find some useful things. I'll continue investigating.